# angular $routeProvider resolve

Tags: angularjs

I want to create my menu dynamically, for that, I use resolve before loading the dashboard.

```
var app = angular.module('mabnaaApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ur.file'])
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginCtrl'
        })
        .when('/dashboard', {
            templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html',
            resolve: {
                menu: function (MenuService) {
                    return MenuService.getMenu();
                }
            },
            controller: function ($scope, menu) {
                $scope.menu = menu;
                $scope.oneAtATime = true;
            }
        })
        .when('/flatFile', {
            templateUrl: 'views/flatFile.html'
        })
        .when('/view/:vtId/:prId', {
            templateUrl: 'views/viewDetail.html',
            controller: 'ViewDetailController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/login'
        });
}).factory('MenuService', function ($q, $http) {
    var getMenu = function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.post('/m1Object/menu', 1).
            success(function (data) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }).
            error(function (data, status, header, config) {
                $log.warn(data, status, header(), config);
                deferred.reject(status);
            });
        return deferred.promise;
    };

    return{
        getMenu: getMenu
    }
});
```

my menu load perfectly and after that I create my menu in dashboard.

```
    <accordion close-others="oneAtATime"><!--nashta-->
    <accordion-group heading="{{project.name}}" ng-repeat="project in menu.projectName">

        <accordion close-others="oneAtATime"><!--bank-->
            <accordion-group heading="{{bank.name}}" ng-repeat="bank in menu.bankingList" is-disabled="bank.value == null? true:false">

                <accordion close-others="oneAtATime"><!--working pack-->
                    <accordion-group heading="{{wp.name}}" ng-repeat="wp in menu.workingPackList" is-disabled="wp.value == null? true:false">

                        <accordion close-others="oneAtATime"><!--product pack-->
                            <accordion-group heading="{{pr.name}}" ng-repeat="pr in menu.productList" is-disabled="pr.value == null? true:false">

                                <accordion ng-repeat="vt in menu.viewType">
                                    <li ng-controller="ViewDetailController"><a href="/app/index.html#/view/{{pr.value}}/{{vt.value}}" ancher-cheking ng-click="getViewDetail">{{vt.name}}</a></li>
                                </accordion>

                            </accordion-group>
                        </accordion>

                    </accordion-group>
                </accordion>

            </accordion-group>
        </accordion>
    </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

now user can select one of viewType to see the detail in viewDetail.html. I want call getViewDetail from ViewDetailController controller to handel it.

```
                                    <accordion ng-repeat="vt in menu.viewType">
                                    <li ng-controller="ViewDetailController"><a href="/app/index.html#/view/{{pr.value}}/{{vt.value}}" ancher-cheking ng-click="getViewDetail">{{vt.name}}</a></li>
                                </accordion>
```

but I don`t know what happen when the menu is creating,the getViewDetail function of ViewDetailController controller is called!!!
my point is getViewDetail from ViewDetailController is called before my menu create completely and without clicking on any menu.

[image]

ViewDetailController:

```
    .controller('ViewDetailController', function ($scope, $modal, $routeParams, $log, ViewDetailService) {

    var getViewDetail = function () {
        var list = ViewDetailService.getViewDetail($routeParams.prId, $routeParams.vtId);
        list.then(
            function (result) {
                $scope.list = result;

            }, function (status) {
            });
    };
```

what is my problem?why getViewDetail function is called during the creation of menu?

Comment: Can you try using `ng-click="getViewDetail()"`

Comment: Can you replicate in fiddle/plunker ?

Comment: @DivyaMV I try it but it didn't chang

Comment: in the developer tools check the call stack on this debug point in the last image , you can see which piece of code initiated the getViewDetail()